# Alamofire Singleton Return Handler

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to create a networking singleton for my alamofire request so that in order to call my API, I only have to do something like this:

```
Services.sharedInstance.useAlamo { (result: Array) in

        case .success: 

            self.userarray = result

            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.tableView.dataSource = self

            print (result)

       case .failure:

            print ("Request Failed")

}
```

I have the singleton set up and can pass the results through but am not sure how to add the enum to the completion block so that I can use .success or .failure when I call the singleton. So far I tried doing something like this but received error:

```
enum Results<Value> {
            case success(Value)
            case failure(Error)

        }

struct Services {

    static let sharedInstance = Services()

    func useAlamo(finished: @escaping (_ result: [User]) -> Results<String>) {

        var userarray: [User] = []

        Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").validate().responseData { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .success:

                if let data = response.result.value {

                    userarray = try! JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)

                    finished(userarray)

                    return .success("string") // Error here: "Type 'Void' has no member 'success'"

                }
            case .failure:

                finished(userarray)

                return .failure("stringfailure") // Error here: "Type 'Void' has no member 'failure'"
            }
        }

    }

}
```

**Update**: The goal is to get an enum of success and failure to get called from the completion block. The suggested duplicate question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I know that, I was trying to get some feedback on how to get a .success or .failure enum from a completion handler which is possible. Your duplicate suggestion has nothing to do with that, please remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of issues. The most important issue is that you can't return a value from an asynchronous completion handler.

Using your enum declare the `useAlamo` function without a return value but passing a `Results` object in the closure. On success pass an `User` array, on failure pass an `Error`. You have to add appropriate errors, either an error returned by the Alamofire call or a self created one. Instead of the `return` statements call the `finished` closure.

The code is untested because I don't use Alamofire. It will not compile because the `error` objects are missing. But you'll get an impression of the workflow

```
struct Services {

    static let sharedInstance = Services()

    func useAlamo(finished: @escaping (Results<[User]>) -> () ) {

        Alamofire.request("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").validate().responseData { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:

                if let data = response.result.value {
                    let userarray = try! JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)
                    finished(.success(userarray))
                } else {
                    // create an error
                    finished(.failure(error))
                }
            case .failure:
                finished(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On the calling side switch on the `result` and handle the associated values

```
var userarray = [User]()

Services.sharedInstance.useAlamo { result in

    switch result {
    case .success(let users):

        self.userarray = users
        self.tableView.reloadData()

        print(users)

    case .failure(let error):

        print ("Request Failed", error)
    }
}
```